# Why do I get a high peak in my FFT plot of a 50 Hz sine wave?

Tags: power, fft

I am plotting the FFT of my signal that is stored in "Array" format obtained from simulation. The signal is a sine wave of 50 Hz so I get a peak at 50 Hz. The problem is that the value is way too high. What is the problem in my code, can someone see it?

```
figure
plot(data1(2534947:2898217,1),data1(2534947:2898217,2))

Ydata1 = data1(2534947:2898217,2);
tstart = data1(2534947); 
tend = data1(2898217);

t_stop = tend-tstart;

Ts = data1(2534940,1)-data1(2534939,1);
Fs = 1/Ts; % Sampling frequency

t = 0:Ts:t_stop-Ts;

nfft = length(Ydata1); % Length of FFT
nfft2 = 2^nextpow2(nfft); % Make it to the power 2

X = fft(Ydata1,nfft2); % Take FFT
X = X(1:nfft2/2); % FFT is symmetric, throw away second half

mx = abs(X); % Take the magnitude of fft of x
f = (0:nfft2/2-1)*Fs/nfft2;% Frequency vector

figure
plot(f,mx); % Generate plot
```

The signal:
[image]

FFT plot:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've changed one line of the code, and now it is normalized:

plot(f,mx./(max(abs(X))));

Comment: The expected value of the peak is infinity. The peak being a dirac delta pulse.

Comment: It gives the power, so why infinity? It definitely shouldn't be equal to infinity power

Comment: Why do you think that the peak is too high? What value were you expecting to see? Hint: think carefully about what *units* are associated with the vertical scale in your second graph.

Comment: Make sure you understand whether the FFT that's being done has a unit, sqrt(N) or an N scaling. If you don't know what I'm talking about, now's the time to find out. As a tip, most of the time I couldn't be bothered to research what the particular FFT in the particular language I was using was actually doing for scaling, so I'd just run a known waveform through it, like you have, and call that the calibration waveform.

Comment: I can't add 3 figures at this moment... but with that piece of code I now get it equal to 1 instead of a very high peak which is much better so I normalized it. But how can I plot it as: Magnitude % of fundamental vs harmonic order plot?

Comment: @KevinEngelshofen "It gives the power, so why infinity? It definitely shouldn't be equal to infinity power "

This isn't how the dirac delta works, its a funky function, integral over the diract delta = 1, the total power is the integral over the fourier transform, its meaningless to talk about power in an infinitesimally thin band (dirac delta).

Comment: Basically, your model (50HZ) and Fourier are done on the same system with same system epsilon, therefore you coincidentally compute near infinite (very large) power at precisely the 50HZ band. Any physical 50HZ signal you measure will not look like this.

Comment: I strongly second @Neil_UK 's comment. There are many scale factors that go into FFT calculations; you can either try to keep track of them, or "calibrate them out" by feeding a waveform of known frequency and amplitude (I would suggest and amplitude of 1) - then divide your result accordingly. Doing this for a couple of different amplitudes and frequencies will teach you a lot about your algorithm and give you a better intuition as well.

Comment: As for the problem of adding multiple plots... if you plot multiple graphs in one plot (`subplot(3,1,1)` etc) you can post as many as you would like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all looks normal to me.   By Parseval's theorem, the sum-of-squares of the input function's samples is equal to the sum-of-squares of the transformed values.   A comment indicates 'it gives the power', but the sum-square of those values
is NOT the power, it is the ENERGY.   Power, in the transform, is
the square peak height times the bandwidth (i.e. an area under a peak).
By taking multiple cycles, the bandwidth is diminished and the peak
height goes up.